# Connecting JProfiler to a remote host

Tags: profiling, jprofiler

I'm trying to profile a web application that is on a remote host/server using JProfiler, but the process seems to be a more complicated than i imagined.

I already managed to profile locally on my Dev working copy, but the results aren't useful there.

Is there a way to connect JProfiler to that server without having to install it on the remote machine/server, because that's not an option that i have. something like remote debugging, where i configure the host and port and connect.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

As of 9.2, you have to extract the JProfiler tar.gz on the remote host and run `bin/jpenable' to prepare a running JVM for profiling. Then you can connect with a remote session from your local JProfiler installation.

In JProfiler 10, you will just need an SSH connection, without any remote installation required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! May i ask when can we expect v10 to be released?

Comment: It will be released in Q1/2107, I cannot give a precise date.